# Converting TSQL query to Oracle not working

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, database-migration

I've got a tsql query in SQL Server that works fine. But when I use it inside an execute sql task in ssis to run against an Oracle DB. I get errors for 'function not allowed in group'. I know that Oracle's grouping is different but I'm not well versed with it to know enough.

How do I convert this tsql query into oracle - sql:

```
SELECT 
    TBL_A.EID AS MYID
    , TBL_A.ID
    , TBL_B.LOGIN AS LOGID  
    , TO_DATE(TBL_B.CM, 'MM/DD/YYYY') as MD 
    , sum(TBL_B.CS) as TTS
    , sum(TBL_B.COTS) as HTS
    , sum(TBL_B.CWS) as WTS
    , sum(TBL_B.CL) as NTS
FROM 
    SRVR1.TBL1 TBL_A JOIN
    SRVR2.TBL2 TBL_B
    ON TBL_A.ID = TBL_B.LOGIN

GROUP BY
    TBL_A.EID
    ,TBL_A.ID
    ,TBL_B.LOGIN
    ,TO_DATE(TBL_B.CM, 'MM/DD/YYYY') as MD  

ORDER BY TBL_B.LOGIN,
    TBL_B.CM    ;
```

Comment: `group by sum(..)` make no sense at all. Neither in Oracle nor in SQL Server. What exactly is your `DATEFROMPARTS` doing? And there is no `year()` function in Oracle. Did you write that yourself? What is the intention of the `rownum < 5` there? That is [not going to work](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/pseudocolumns009.htm#SQLRF00255) the way you think. And please add the **exact** error message to your question.

Comment: Regardless of which DBMS you are using you should use the ANSI-92 style joins. It has been more than 25 years since it was introduced. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: There is no chance that query is working as posted in sql server. You have aggregates in the group by and you also have columns aliased in the group by. Have you considered converting to date instead of all those functions to turn a datetime into a date?

Comment: Also remove the column alias (`as MD`) from the `GROUP BY` clause.  A `group by` clause should **not** be a cut-n-paste of the `select` clause!

Comment: The datefromparts functions could be simplified to this. convert(date, getdate())

Comment: @SeanLange: there is no `convert()` in Oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest starting with a query like this:

```
SELECT TBL_A.EID AS MYID, TBL_A.ID AS LOGID  
       DATEFROMPARTS(year(TBL_B.CM), month(TBL_B.CM), day(TBL_B.CM)) as MD 
       sum(TBL_B.CS) as TTS,
       sum(TBL_B.COTS) as HTS,
       sum(TBL_B.CWS) as WTS,
       sum(TBL_B.CL) as NUM
FROM SRVR1.TBL1 TBL_A JOIN
     SRVR2.TBL2 TBL_B
     ON TBL_A.ID = TBL_B.LOGIN
WHERE rownum < 5
GROUP BY TBL_A.EID, TBL_A.ID, TBL_B.LOGIN,
          DATEFROMPARTS(year(TBL_B.CM),month(TBL_B.CM),day(TBL_B.CM)) 
ORDER BY TBL_B.LOGIN, TBL_B.CM ;
```

Notes:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax.
- Don't put aggregation functions like `SUM()` in the `GROUP BY`.
- Why have `id` and `login` in the `SELECT`?  The `JOIN` condition specifies that they are the same.

In addition:

- `datefromparts()` is a SQL Server-only function
- `year()`, `month()`, and `day()` are SQL Server-only
- `rownum` is Oracle-only
- And the `rownum` before the `GROUP BY` just returns 5 arbitrary rows that are then aggregated.

I'm not sure what your query should really be.  It would look different in SQL Server versus Oracle.

Comment: I'd at least throw in a caveat that the `where` would be applied before the `group by` and `order by` so this won't return the "top 5 aggregate rows", it'll take 5 arbitrary rows, group them, and order the results.  That seems unlikely to be correct.

Comment: I just added the rownum as a substitute for top n in sql server. This is a half baked query that I was trying to convert. How do I do the oracle version of datefromparts?

Comment: @DamonMatt . . . Something using `to_date()`.

Comment: Made the changes for oracle and changed original post - still getting 'sql command not properly ended' error.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff - I need the first two columns in my dataset.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff's answer pointed me in the right direction, although it wasn't the complete answer. Accepting it as answer.